# Using Blender on a Computer in another room

Tags: hardware

So the situation is that I have a PC in a room in my house and I would like to be able to use that PC whilst I'm in another room, bear with me, as I have just started a family and don't want to be spending my time separated from my wife and child.  The computer is a meaty thing and I want to be able to use that but from the comfort of my living room.

What kind of options are there?  One thing I'm looking at is using my old laptop with Remote Desktop to access the PC but it is and old clunky laptop, is this a good way of going?  Does Remote Desktop essentially allow me to use the power of my big PC via the screen of my laptop? (seems unlikely) I've looked into Wifi Monitors, massive cables etc but was looking for a way to keep it light.  I want to use Blender and Davinici Resolve, is this a nonsense or is it possible? Will the speed of the laptop effect the speed that Blender operates at or is it merely video feed?

Any ideas would be great.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows you should avoid the built in Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). It will prevent you from using OpenGL, making it impossible to use blender.

Use an app like RealVNC or TeamViewer. Blender works perfectly with those apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so with Teamviewer is it just streaming a video feed to the laptop and what would cause any lag? Speed of the laptop? Speed of the Wifi?

Comment: Controlling blender remotely will always be slower than when operating the host machine. The fastest the network, the better experience, but expect it to be like when you are sitting at your desk. The portable computer that is controlling the remote computer doesn't have to be a very fast machine, the heavy lifting is done on the remote one. Using a laptop's trackpad instead of a mouse is not as fun. Forget about using Resolve remotely in a setup like the one you propose. Remote sessions in Resolve require both computers to be quite fast and with a proper monitor.

Comment: If what you are trying is not to be separated from wife and child... turn the computer off and enjoy their company...

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, it helps me earn money to buy them nice things.

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon to render using another computer, it's called netrender and it should be already in blender. Here's the instructions and stuff: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender

I hope this helps you